# MongoDB adding field by regex condition

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Consider this simple collection:

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b6fbcb328d62424ece9265b"), 
    "name" : "abc"
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b6fbcbd28d62424ece9265c"), 
    "name" : "cde"
}
```

I want to add a field `hasA` which determines there is any 'a' character in `name` field in an aggregation query, so my expected output should be like this:

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b6fbcb328d62424ece9265b"), 
    "name" : "abc",
    "hasA" : true
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b6fbcbd28d62424ece9265c"), 
    "name" : "cde",
    "hasA" : false
}
```

I have tested this aggregation query but it returns wrong output:

```
$addFields
{
    "hasA": { $cond : [ {name : /a/}, true, false ] }
}
```

output:

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b6fbcb328d62424ece9265b"), 
    "name" : "abc", 
    "hasA" : true
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b6fbcbd28d62424ece9265c"), 
    "name" : "cde", 
    "hasA" : true
}
```

I have tested many data with this query but it seems that it returns always true as result.

Comment: I don't know Mongo regex syntax, but if the regex match applies to the entire string, then you'll have to use something like `{name : /.*a.*/}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use regular expressions in Aggregation Framework (JIRA ticket [here](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-11947)). If you just need to check if string contains substring you can use [$indexOfBytes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/indexOfBytes/) operator which returns `-1` if there's no match:

```
db.col.aggregate([
    {
        $addFields: {
            "hasA": { $cond : [ { $eq: [ { $indexOfBytes: [ "$name", "a" ] }, -1 ] }, false, true ] }
        }
    }
])
```

Answer (score 1):

It's possible in Mongo 4.2 and up by using `$regexMatch`.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      "hasA": {
        $regexMatch: { input: "$name", regex: "a" }
      }
    }
  }
])
```